# send chunk data and handle it front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I have few problem

1. Suppose user request to download csv and database have 100k record. in my 
   node server first i read a 10 record from table and write it into file and 
   response to front end for that i m using response.write method it this 
   method is correct ?. again i read next 10 record and write it into file 
   this continues till all data reading and writing file complete then it send 
   final response in front end.
2. Now i front end it show loading till all write operation finished in node 
   server
3. As soon as server finished file creation it will automatically download 
   started in front end
   can anyone suggested me. how i can achieve above scenario note i don't want to use socket

---

```
for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
    res.write(i)
}
res.end
```

Comment: show what you have tried till now

Comment: @jitender for backend it tried this much only actually i don't know how i can do so i m create my post over here